How to scan barcode to windows form in background without interrupting the foreground application. Zebra DS22 Barcode Scanner?
How to scan barcode to windows form in background without interrupting the foreground application. Zebra DS22 Barcode Scanner?
Hi,

I am a C# .net web developer,
i need to receive input from barcode scanner without interrupting the foreground application.
in other words i need the barcode scanner to send data to the background application.

i need help or guide on where do i need start, or how can i achieve this.
is it possible?
TIA
i assume that i need a windows application to achieve this.
i already installed .net Desktop Application (windows forms), VS2022
i don't know how to integrate barcode scanner to the desktop application.

The ideas in the "In Addition" part of the answer in this article may be helpful. How do I distinguish between a scanner input and keyboard input in Javascript? The easiest thing to do is to switch to serial port mode instead of keyboard emulation mode.

Zebra scanners usually have afew different profiles. HID emulates a keyboard. You probably want SPP which emulates a serial port, see the Zebra docs.

Most all barcode scanners emulate as an USB keyboard, so you need to be looking for how to capture keyboard inputs.
Check out global keyboard hook/Raw input Capture keyboard input. Or search for other answers about global keyboard capture.
If you want to use the users normal keyboard elsewhere , then you need to get creative. I've used luamacros to do this before, however its been discontinued.
The key is that luamacros can driver inject based on vendor id , so it can capture only the keyboard of the barcode scanner.Its not a pretty solution at all cause you need to use a different language( Lua ) and you need to babysit it too( start it up , make sure it does not lose its binding etc) and also integrate it with your application.

If you use a barcode scanner as a POS device, it is recommended to use the POS for .NET to integrate the barcode scanner. This framework allows you to implement advanced features such as device declaration, enablement, and data event processing.
If you do not use a POS system and just need simple barcode data input, it is recommended to configure the barcode scanner to keyboard emulation mode or use serial port mode for data transmission. After the scanner is configured in keyboard emulation mode, you only need to process standard keyboard input events to receive barcode data. If you need more precise control, you can use the SerialPort class to communicate with the scanner's serial port and read the barcode data directly.

@Password I'd like to ask if the solution in this answer is useful, or if you found another solution?
